# Is a 5.5V to 15V GPIO a suitable controller for a 120V/30A relay?

Tags: relay

I'm trying to create a simple computer-controlled switch for some speakers that plug into my home 120V outlets.

I was thinking I could cut a surge protector or extension cord open, and wire [this relay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DWI41NE) to the cables.

I'd want to then plug [this controller](https://www.pololu.com/product/3101) into my computer, and then write some simple driver that would let me turn the relay on and off.

I have no experience with relays. I read up on them and know that's what I need, but I don't know how to tell how much Amperage or Voltage you would need to use to power the change between an open and close circuit here.

Controller specs:

```
Processor:  ATmega32U4 @ 16 MHz
RAM size:   2560 bytes
Program memory size:    32 Kbytes
Motor channels: 0
User I/O lines: 15
Minimum operating voltage:  5.5 V
Maximum operating voltage:  15 V
Logic voltage:  5 V
Reverse voltage protection?:    Y
```

Relay:

```
American Zettler, Inc. 
AZ2280-1A-120AF RELAY; 
POWER; 
MINIATURE; 
30A; 
SPST; 
120VAC; 
1 FORM A;
```

Given the specs of the relay and the controller.. Would this work? How can I tell?

Comment: Note that the A-Star 32U4 Micro board can be operated from 5.5 to 12 volts, the microcontroller itself is operated from a regulated 5 volts generated on the board, so the voltage on its I/O pins must be limited to 5 volts.

Comment: so that means I should expect no more than 5 volts coming out of thie I/O pins, yes? And therefore I need a relay that has a 5V coil?

Comment: Yes - the maximum output voltage from the micro will be 5 volts, but you will probably need to use that to drive a transitor to handle the current needed to drive the relay.

Comment: Also, the inputs to the microcontroller must be limited to 5 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the datasheet](http://www.azettler.com/pdfs/az2280.pdf) says, the -120AF has a 120VAC coil. Unfortunately you won't be able to activate this with a GPIO. Find a -5DF instead, and use the normal combination of [transistor and flyback diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102307/why-do-i-need-a-transistor-to-control-a-relay-with-an-arduino-and-which-one-sho) to run it off 5V and your GPIO.

Comment: Am I correct that I need a 120V coil here, since this is going to be plugged into my home AC? Does the amperage sound OK? I was thinking 15-30 Amps should do it.

Comment: Your contacts must be rated for mains voltage. Your coil needs to be rated for control voltage. A NEMA 5-15R outlet is rated for (surprise!) 15A, so that part is covered (since form A can switch 30A).

Comment: thanks for your help! would I still need a transistor with [this relay](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HR8NSNE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)?

Comment: @tmsimont: The coil needs 90mA, so yes, a transistor would be needed.

Comment: it kind of looks like [this thing](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008MU1OBY/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A1THAZDOWP300U) has the relay, transistor and diode all on one board... is this all i need?

Comment: The sole reviewer claims that it works with a RPi, so I believe that it would be. A schematic would seal the deal.